# FizzBuzz range above 1 is not working

Tags: javascript, fizzbuzz

I've made a function which solves the Fizz Buzz challenge. Now, the user can fill in 6 variables.

Names instead of Fizz and Buzz.. The range (normally 0 to 100) and on which numbers it should check if it is divisable.

```
for(var i = rangeone; i < rangetwo ; i++){
    console.log(i)
    if(i % divisiontwo === 0 && i % divisionone === 0){
        endarray.push(bothwords)
    }else if(i % divisiontwo === 0){
        endarray.push(secondword)
    }else if(i % divisionone === 0){
        endarray.push(firstword)
    }else{
        endarray.push(i)
    }
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/cuhna8rt/)

The problem is. If you fill in the range, Normally you would fill in 0 to 100. If you fill in 1 to 100 it still works.. but if you fill in 2 to 100 (or 2+ to 250 it doesnt matter) it doesn't work anymore.

I am not able to figure out WHY it doesn't. Apparently it doesn't even run the for loop if rangeone is higher as 1 for(i = rangeone; i < rangetwo; i++)

Can someone explain this to me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're working with strings, not numbers. `"2"` is greater than `"100"`, therefore your loop never runs.

Comment: well, for one, why are you assigning strings to your `divisionx` variables? You're doing MATH, which means you should be assigning numbers....

Comment: But why does it work with for example 0 and 100? and now with 2 and 100? There shouldn't be a difference there if it didnt accept strings either way. right?

Comment: Wrong. *Some* JavaScript operators will convert your strings to numbers, but not all (especially not the comparison operators).

Comment: Ah oke. Thank you for the comment. It is appreciated! I'll do some research into this.. New to all this and definetly looking over simple stuff sometimes :D

Answer (score 1):

`for (i = parseInt(rangeone); i < parseInt(rangetwo); i++) {`

Convert the input strings into numbers.

Comment: Hmm oke. That seems to solve it. Thank you! Yet I am still flabbergasted by the fact that I was sending strings.. yet it accepted "1" and "2" as ranges